# Ajax/Jquery - getting a record on a response to submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that submits to a DB using Ajax/jquery. The form is processed by a php page, and successfully submits the data to mysql.  But I want it to return the values submitted to the database, so I can display them on the page.

I am just learning so I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I am able to get it to return the mysql table's record id number in an alert. After that alert I can a second alert which I thought would return the data submitted, but the alert only says undefined.

I can't figure out how to get it to return the data, if anyone could help, it would be great.

This is the Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('form.quform').Quform({
    successStart: function (response) {
        alert(response.record.id);
        alert(response.record.content);
    }
});
```

The table's name is `account_data`, the fields are `bank_name, balance, acc_number, monthly`

post php info:

```
if (isset($_POST['form_ajax']) && $_POST['form_ajax'] == 1) {
    $result['record'] = $config['record'];
```

mysql array php:

```
 $config['record'] = array(
'id' => mysql_insert_id(),
'bank_name' => $form->getValue('bank_name') 
'balance' => $form->getValue('balance')
'acc_number' => $form->getValue('acc_number')
'monthly' => $form->getValue('monthly')
```

);

To summarize, it adds the record successfully, returns the record id number in the first alert and then gives an undefined error in the 2nd alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your console so know exactly what gets returned:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form.quform').Quform({
    successStart: function (response) {
      console.log(response);  
    }
  }
);
```

Check your console to see what you receive.

Also good to check: the PHP json_encode() and in jquery the parseJson() method.

Comment: It gets it to go into the console using the method you suggested suggested, is there a way to get it into an alert or a div on the page?

Comment: Yes, the only catch is you have to alert a string and not an object. So check in your console the exact structure of the object and use that to target the correct data.